# Sans serif math with corrected spacing

Tags: fonts, math-mode, spacing, sans-serif

With the `sfmath` package I find that there is too little space between some symbols. In an expression like `$n_1$` for instance the subscript is too close to the base. Although the space between the symbols seems to be the same as with the computer modern font the space will look larger with the latter font because of the serif of the n which pushes the subscript a little to the right. Does anyone know if there is a space corrected version of sans serif math?

Comment: I guess this would depend on the kerning tables of the font used. Is this only true for Computer Modern Sans (which is not the most carefully crafted fonts there is AFAIK) or did you try other fonts as well? You don't happen to have some pretty pictures to illustrate the problem?

Comment: You may consider the `sansmathaccent` package, which addresses some problems in using `sfmath`; I guess that the package author will be glad to get feedback.

Comment: egreg: Thanks for the tip. However, I use Helvetica and the sansmathaccent package only address the default Computer Modern sans serif font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no chance to get correct spacing if the font has not been especially designed for math, because it requires fine tuning of many parameters.

There is a commercial `hvmath` font (http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/hvmath/hvmain.htm), with the free versions there's not much to do.